# When and how the phrase "beyond the call of duty" used?

Tags: history

I have seen this phrase used many times 
But couldn't find its original use or reference.

Comment: iamgopal, It’s a pitty if this question gets closed. I could try to get it reopened, but you’d need to improve it first. The title needs fixing: maybe *when and how […] was first used?* For questions about origin of words and phrases, as this one, it’s a good thing to check [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=beyond+the+call+of+duty)  report what it says about the origin of the phrase (nothing in this case), and ask about the things it leaves unanswered. >>

Comment: >> If you do this there’s a good chance, I think, enough people will vote to reopen the question. I’d like to add a few things to my answer, but I’m reluctant to do so while the question is on hold or if it gets closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase, if not coined, appears to have been popularised by the American armed forces during World War I. According to [this article](http://www.homeofheroes.com/moh/history/history.html), following discontent at the ease with which the Medal of Honour was awarded (emphasis mine in all quotes):

> in 1916, President Woodrow Wilson signed a law requiring the War Department to set up a commission of distinguished generals and admirals to review all previous medal awards.
>
> At the same time, the services created a series of lesser medals to honor acts of courage.  The Medal of Honor would only be awarded for actions **“above and beyond the call of duty”** and in actual combat.

Then, from 1919 onwards an identical sentence―“for conspicuous gallantry and intrepidity, **above and beyond the call of duty**, in action with the enemy” somewhere in France―appears repeatedly.  Here’s the earliest example I could find, from [*The Story of the 91st Division*, 91st Division Publication Committee, 1919:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9qkBAAAAMAAJ&q=%22beyond%20the%20call%20of%20duty%22&dq=%22beyond%20the%20call%20of%20duty%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT-aXLsobTAhUH3IMKHbJnBIUQ6AEIazAR)

> MILLER, OSCAR F., MAJOR, 361ST INFANTRY. For conspicuous gallantry and intrepidity, **above and beyond the call of duty**, in action with the enemy near Gesne, France, September 28, 1918. [p. 92.]
>
> KATZ, PHILLIP C., SARGEANT, CO. C, 363RD INFANTRY. For conspicuous gallantry and intrepidity, **above and beyond the call of duty**, in action with the enemy near Eclisfontaine, France, September 26, 1918. [p. 93.]

Answer (score 2):

This is *call* in its original sense of *speaking out*. Duty is personified, so its call are the demands that duty makes on you. Children should heed their parents, citizens should heed the police, the police should protect the citizens selflessly. People aren't always perfect and most relations (as in family) are supposed to be more about love than duty anyway.

So "the call of duty" is most commonly employed for police officers, firemen, soldiers, &c. who have sworn themselves to serve others and have no ties to them apart from that duty. There are minimum expectations of their behavior, but there are upper bounds too. Everyone understands the cop who waits for backup or the soldier who waits for air cover.

Going *beyond* that is when such people show extraordinary bravery, usually because of some emergency where they opt to help another or others at great risk to themselves, rather than wait for help or claim incapacity.

Comment: As far as first use, just keep in mind that the *Online Etymology Dictionary* is about as spotty as *Urban Dictionary*. The only serious resource is going to be the *OED* or one of its equivalents for Middle or Old English. In this case, the first use of "call of duty" is a 1660 broadside of the English officers swearing their commitment to keeping down the Irish.

Comment: Your comparison of etymonline and Urban Dictionary is inconsistent. Etymonline is a scholarly enterprise (by a single person) using many sources but relying mostly on OED. Urban Dictionary is crowd sourced but with no editing/curating mechanisms at all, good for  finding out about current slang, but not about reliable word histories older than 20 years.